# Transalting from English to Chinese on Python Django

Tags: django, translation, chinese-locale, chinese-simplified

I'm trying to convert my web-app to a couple of different languages in Python Django. I have managed to do so for English and French but the problem comes in when I add the zh hans or zh-cn. I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3V7L.png)

Here's my settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import cloudinary
import os
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _



BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent




# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []




# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'go',
    'crispy_forms',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'cloudinary',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/
# Set the default language for your project.
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'


LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('zh-cn', u'简体中文'),
    
]

# Enable localization by setting USE_I18N to True.
USE_I18N = True

# Set the directory where Django will look for translation files.
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),  # You can create a 'locale' directory in your project's base directory.
]

TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Nairobi'
```

My Locale structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzz6F.png)

And my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.utils.translation import get_language, activate, gettext

def homex(request):
    trans = translate(language='zh_cn')
    return render(request, 'homex.html', {'trans': trans})

def translate(language):
    cur_language = get_language()
    try:
        activate(language)
        text = gettext('hello')
    finally:
        activate(cur_language)
    return text
```

What could I be doing wrong?

The expected result is for the Hello text to be translated into Chinese